# Scaffold-DbContext failed to build, how do i resolve this issue on Nuget console?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nuget

I have installed all required packages for this command, when i try to run this command on my console its failed to build. Kindly please assist to resolve this issue, thanks.

```
PM> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=Gcobanim-L\SQLEXPRESS;Database=eNtsaRegistration;Trusted_Connection=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
Build started...
Build failed.
```

Comment: Add `-Verbose` flag to your command to see what is failing: `Scaffold-DbContext ...  -Verbose`

Comment: @Guru Stron i have and its not showing where the error of failing is coming and dont know now.

Comment: What output are you getting with it?

Comment: After you execute this command on nuget console,did you get any error from Error List? If so, please share with us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First rebuild the project and see any errors and were fixed.
2. Execute the command again and ran successfully without any issue.
3. Update-Database also build successfully.

Comment: I can't rebuild the project without the scaffolded code. I can't scaffold the required code without building the project. What should I do know?

Comment: @user1969903 use `--no-build` flag which works with `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` command

Answer (score 0):

For command line tool `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` there is a flag `--no-build`:

`--no-build    Don't build the project. Intended to be used when the build is up-to-date.`